# Delete all drafts?

Tags: posts, database, query

This is a common query to delete all post revisions:

```
DELETE a,b,c
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
WHERE a.post_type = 'revision'
```

Will this work to delete all drafts?

```
DELETE a,b,c
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
WHERE a.post_type = 'draft'
```

and is it better than this since it also deletes postmeta?

```
 DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_status = ‘draft’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`draft` is not a `post_type`, it's a `post_status`. So you should use your second block of code with that substitution:

```
DELETE a,b,c
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
WHERE a.post_status = 'draft'
```

Answer (score 0):

**I would suggest if u want to delete any post manually from wp_posts. you need to perform the following steps:-**

1. **Remove from postmeta table.**

```sql
delete FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN
    (
        select id from wp_posts where post_status='draft'
    );
```

2. **Remove from wp_term_relationships table.**

```sql
delete FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id IN
    (
        select id from wp_posts where post_status='draft'
    );
```

3. **Remove from wp_posts table.**

```sql
delete from wp_posts where post_status='draft'
```